# Access VBA SQL command UPDATE for multiple value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In Access VBA I try to edit column `Desi_DB` table OrderA it is lookup with multiple values. And standard command doesn't work.

```
strSql = "UPDATE OrderA SET Desi_DB = something?? WHERE ID = 3"
```

`something` should be 3 5 9 but not a string '3;5;9'

I tried many ideas with Dlookup and additem and .Value, eg:

```
currentValue = DLookup("Desi_DB", "OrderA", "ID = 3") 
rs.Fields("Desi_DB").AddItem item
rs("Desi_DB").value = newValue
```

Nothing works - please help.

Comment: What do you mean `3 5 9 bu not a string '3;5;9'`?

Comment: it is ID from LookUp table and when I read it Access use separator ; but not allow directly update by string "3;5;9"

Comment: If this is setup as a multi-value field, you need to understand that this is not a normal field. It just holds pointers to records of a hidden table. Cannot treat them same way as normal fields. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-delete-a-multivalued-field-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31#:~:text=1%20Open%20a%20table%20in%20Design%20View%20.,the%20first%20page%2C%20select%20I%20...%20See%20More. I advise not to use multi-value fields nor to set lookups in table. Build a normal related table.

Answer (score 0):

First cleare all values from `Desi_DB` then add values one by one:

```
DELETE Desi_DB.value FROM OrderA WHERE ID = 3
INSERT INTO OrderA (Desi_DB.value) VALUES(3) WHERE ID = 3
INSERT INTO OrderA (Desi_DB.value) VALUES(5) WHERE ID = 3
INSERT INTO OrderA (Desi_DB.value) VALUES(9) WHERE ID = 3
```